# Spring API Gateway don't redirect requests to the other services

Tags: spring-boot, api-gateway

I have a problem with my spring API gateway as I don't get a result when asking for a route.
I have 3 services and I need to send requests only to one API gateway to handle the upcoming request.
When I try and access a service, I don't get this message:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-01-07T16:52:50.076+00:00",
    "path": "/tva/",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": null,
    "requestId": "8527c006-1"
}
```

So I don't get any response.
My service Application.yml file:

```
server:
 port: 9003

spring:
 application:
   name: TVA-SERVICE

eureka:
 instance:
   hostname: localhost
client:
  fetch-registry: true
  register-with-eureka: true
  service-url:
  defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

TThe application.yml file for the API gateway:

```
server:
  port: 9191


spring:
  application:
    name: API-GATEWAY
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: ELECTRICITY-SERVICE
          uri: lb://ELECTRICITY-SERVICE
          predicates:
            - Path=/users/**
            - Path=/bills/**
        - id: TVA-SERVICE
          uri: lb://TVA-SERVICE
          predicates:
            - Path=/tva/**
        - id: BA-SERVICE
          uri: lb://BA-SERVICE
          predicates:
            - Path=/ba/**

      eureka:
        instance:
          hostname: localhost
      client:
        fetch-registry: true
        register-with-eureka: true
        server-url:
          defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

And here is the Application.yml file for the service registry:

```
server:
  port: 8761

eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false
```

Here is the message I get when I run the API gateway:

```
2022-01-07 17:52:33.664  INFO 16600 --- [           main] c.t.c.CloudGatewayApplication            : Starting CloudGatewayApplication using Java 17 on LAPTOP-NQ9LQJBB with PID 16600 (C:\Users\PREDATOR\Desktop\workspace\jee project backend\cloud-gateway\target\classes started by PREDATOR in C:\Users\PREDATOR\Desktop\workspace\jee project backend\cloud-gateway)
2022-01-07 17:52:33.665  INFO 16600 --- [           main] c.t.c.CloudGatewayApplication            : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2022-01-07 17:52:34.305  INFO 16600 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=e884b174-a379-383b-bee7-679825ad255c
2022-01-07 17:52:34.347  INFO 16600 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerBeanPostProcessorAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerBeanPostProcessorAutoConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2022-01-07 17:52:34.348  INFO 16600 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerBeanPostProcessorAutoConfiguration$ReactorDeferringLoadBalancerFilterConfig' of type [org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerBeanPostProcessorAutoConfiguration$ReactorDeferringLoadBalancerFilterConfig] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2022-01-07 17:52:34.348  INFO 16600 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'reactorDeferringLoadBalancerExchangeFilterFunction' of type [org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.reactive.DeferringLoadBalancerExchangeFilterFunction] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2022-01-07 17:52:35.713  INFO 16600 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.commons.util.InetUtils         : Cannot determine local hostname
2022-01-07 17:52:35.964  INFO 16600 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [After]
2022-01-07 17:52:35.964  INFO 16600 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [Before]
2022-01-07 17:52:35.964  INFO 16600 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [Between]
2022-01-07 17:52:35.964  INFO 16600 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [Cookie]
2022-01-07 17:52:35.964  INFO 16600 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [Header]
2022-01-07 17:52:35.964  INFO 16600 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [Host]
2022-01-07 17:52:35.964  INFO 16600 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [Method]
2022-01-07 17:52:35.964  INFO 16600 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [Path]
2022-01-07 17:52:35.964  INFO 16600 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [Query]
2022-01-07 17:52:35.964  INFO 16600 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [ReadBody]
2022-01-07 17:52:35.964  INFO 16600 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [RemoteAddr]
2022-01-07 17:52:35.964  INFO 16600 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [Weight]
2022-01-07 17:52:35.964  INFO 16600 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [CloudFoundryRouteService]
2022-01-07 17:52:37.254  INFO 16600 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.commons.util.InetUtils         : Cannot determine local hostname
2022-01-07 17:52:38.457  INFO 16600 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.commons.util.InetUtils         : Cannot determine local hostname
2022-01-07 17:52:38.516  INFO 16600 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 1 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2022-01-07 17:52:38.632  INFO 16600 --- [           main] DiscoveryClientOptionalArgsConfiguration : Eureka HTTP Client uses RestTemplate.
2022-01-07 17:52:38.666  WARN 16600 --- [           main] iguration$LoadBalancerCaffeineWarnLogger : Spring Cloud LoadBalancer is currently working with the default cache. You can switch to using Caffeine cache, by adding it and org.springframework.cache.caffeine.CaffeineCacheManager to the classpath.
2022-01-07 17:52:38.704  INFO 16600 --- [           main] o.s.c.n.eureka.InstanceInfoFactory       : Setting initial instance status as: STARTING
2022-01-07 17:52:38.734  INFO 16600 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Initializing Eureka in region us-east-1
2022-01-07 17:52:38.737  INFO 16600 --- [           main] c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver      : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
2022-01-07 17:52:38.755  INFO 16600 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Disable delta property : false
2022-01-07 17:52:38.755  INFO 16600 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Single vip registry refresh property : null
2022-01-07 17:52:38.755  INFO 16600 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Force full registry fetch : false
2022-01-07 17:52:38.755  INFO 16600 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application is null : false
2022-01-07 17:52:38.755  INFO 16600 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Registered Applications size is zero : true
2022-01-07 17:52:38.755  INFO 16600 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application version is -1: true
2022-01-07 17:52:38.755  INFO 16600 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server
2022-01-07 17:52:38.965  INFO 16600 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : The response status is 200
2022-01-07 17:52:38.969  INFO 16600 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Starting heartbeat executor: renew interval is: 30
2022-01-07 17:52:38.973  INFO 16600 --- [           main] c.n.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator     : InstanceInfoReplicator onDemand update allowed rate per min is 4
2022-01-07 17:52:38.982  INFO 16600 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Discovery Client initialized at timestamp 1641574358981 with initial instances count: 3
2022-01-07 17:52:38.982  INFO 16600 --- [           main] o.s.c.n.e.s.EurekaServiceRegistry        : Registering application API-GATEWAY with eureka with status UP
2022-01-07 17:52:38.983  INFO 16600 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Saw local status change event StatusChangeEvent [timestamp=1641574358983, current=UP, previous=STARTING]
2022-01-07 17:52:38.984  INFO 16600 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_API-GATEWAY/localhost:API-GATEWAY:9191: registering service...
2022-01-07 17:52:39.010  INFO 16600 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_API-GATEWAY/localhost:API-GATEWAY:9191 - registration status: 204
2022-01-07 17:52:39.148  INFO 16600 --- [           main] o.s.b.web.embedded.netty.NettyWebServer  : Netty started on port 9191
2022-01-07 17:52:39.149  INFO 16600 --- [           main] .s.c.n.e.s.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration : Updating port to 9191
2022-01-07 17:52:40.351  INFO 16600 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.commons.util.InetUtils         : Cannot determine local hostname
2022-01-07 17:52:41.541  INFO 16600 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.commons.util.InetUtils         : Cannot determine local hostname
2022-01-07 17:52:41.557  INFO 16600 --- [           main] c.t.c.CloudGatewayApplication            : Started CloudGatewayApplication in 9.384 seconds (JVM running for 9.926)
2022-01-07 17:57:38.758  INFO 16600 --- [trap-executor-0] c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver      : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
```

Answer (score 1):

I too had same problem, it turned out to be wrong dependency being added. Instead of 'spring-cloud-starter-gateway-mvc', use 'spring-cloud-starter-gateway'. All the other things remain same.
Turns out first dependency is only compatible with some version of java and spring cloud.